# Panel-footer bootstrap with columns, it doesn't appear in the same row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like to have a panel-footer with three columns in Bootstrap.

A text in the first column on the left and two icons in the other columns on the right.

The code below here:

```
<div class="panel-footer clearfix">
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7"><p>Description: Chart </p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-7">
                <span id="logos" class="material-icons"></span>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-9">
                <span id="logos" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div></div></div>
```

The result is:

[image]

They seem to be in three different rows, why ? What is wrong ? And I would like to have the symbols aligned on the top and not on the bottom.

Comment: Looks like `col-md-offset-*` is causing this. Remove it from `div` and check.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem due to use not right of -offset-*.

In my previous answer I used -offset-7 and -offset-9 and they were outside of the bounds. Max numbers of columns in bootstrap 12 columns.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">

                    Description: {{entry.description}}


                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <span id= "logos" class="material-icons" >&#xE85B;</span>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1" >
                    <span id= "logos" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```